# How to determine the optimal amount of buffer size with asyncio/aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

How do we decide the optimal parameter for read() when working with asyncio in python? 12 bytes? 100 bytes?

```
async with self._session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
    chunk_size = 12
    result = ''

    while True:
       chunk = await response.content.read(chunk_size)
          if not chunk:
              break
          elif isinstance(chunk, (bytes, bytearray)):
              data = chunk.decode('utf8')
               result += data
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do we decide the optimal parameter for read() when working with asyncio in python? 12 bytes? 100 bytes?

You can safely choose a much larger number than that. If the number is too small (e.g. just 1), your loop will consist of many calls to `StreamReader.read`, each of which does carry a fixed overhead - it has to check whether there's something in the buffer, and either return a portion of that and update the remaining buffer, or wait for something new to arrive. On the other hand, if the requested size is excessively large, it might in theory require unnecessarily large allocations. But as `StreamReader.read` is allowed to return less data than specified, it never returns a chunk larger than the internal buffer (64 KiB [by default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4cf7bb8e22bf37e6d65bf4cb5618d09c4a8ad612/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L22)), so that's a non-issue.

**In summary**: any number above 1024 or so will do fine because it will be large enough to avoid an unnecessary number of function calls. Requesting more than 65536 is in most cases the same as requesting 65536. I tend to request 1024 bytes when I don't care about absolute best performance (smaller chunks are easier on the eyes when debugging), and a larger value like 16384 when I do. The numbers don't have to be powers of 2, btw, it's just convention from the more low-level languages.

When dealing specifically with aiohttp streams, you can call [`readany`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/streams.html#aiohttp.StreamReader.readany), a method that just returns whatever data is available, and if nothing is available, waits for some data to arrive and returns that. That is probably the best option if you're dealing with aiohttp streams because it just gives you the data from the internal buffer without having to wonder about its size.

Comment: Super helpful answer!


I checked the buffer limit in asyncio/streams.py, do you mind updating your answer: _DEFAULT_LIMIT = 2 ** 16  # 64 KiB

Comment: Also, is your intuition that read(2**16) or readany() from a buffer in the same process is fast enough to be run in a single coroutine (no real-world benefit in breaking down to smaller chunks)?

Comment: @v1z3 Good catch, I've now corrected the default buffer size value. I'm not sure what you mean by "fast enough to be run in a single coroutine" - it's not like you could speed it up by reading the same stream from multiple coroutines.

Comment: @v1z3 In most code I don't see a benefit in artificially creating smaller chunks than those that were actually received from the network. If the code _does_ require smaller chunks for some domain-specific reason, then it'd definitely make sense and be more efficient to request such chunks from asyncio to begin with. But such code is IMHO quite rare, typical code either doesn't care about chunk size (such as the code in your question), or has more specific requirements of the chunk (such as that it ends on a newline or EOF, as provided by `readline()`).

Comment: Thanks! I did a few benchmarks and answered my own speculative question.