# How to implement logic like sock.recv(), based on python-asyncio's transport & protocol api?

Tags: python, tcp, python-asyncio

I'm trying to build some simple applications based on asyncio tcp. In traditional socket programming, we use sock.recv() and sock.send() to manage the receiving and sending of sockets, but I noticed that using sockets directly is not recommended according to asyncio documentation, correspondingly, they suggest using the transport abstraction.

I want to know how to use transport to reproduce a logic similar to traditional socket programming. For example I'd like to implement the following logic:

```py
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    transport, protocal = await loop.create_connection(EchoClientProtocol(), '', 25000)
    await transport.write("hello")
    await transport.read(5) # Error
    ....
```

The above code does not work because transport does not provide a read method in the begining, the read event must be implemented in the corresponding protocol. This prevents me from clearly separating different tcp packages. What is the right way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: It entirely depends what protocol you're implementing on top of TCP, which you haven't told us. Is it a line-oriented protocol? Is it text-based like HTML? Does it use application-level messages? If so, how are they delimited? You have to actually implement the protocol which depends heavily on what the protocol is.

Comment: Thanks for reply, what I'd like to do is to implement a inter-process communication using my own protocol based on TCP. So I didn't specify the protocol in the subject.

Comment: Then I'm not sure how we can help you. You are asking about the part of the code that implements the protocol. You need to implement whatever your protocol requires, which we don't know because you aren't telling us. If it's a line-based protocol, write code to send and receive lines. If it's a message-based protocol, write code to send and receive messages as they are defined in your protocol. If it's a streaming protocol, write code to send and receive streaming data. Etc.

Comment: Despite the name which sounds close to your needs, you probably **don't** want to use the transport/protocol layer of asyncio. It's a low-level tool more suited for libraries. You almost certainly want to use the [streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) layer, which provides exactly the API you want, such as `StreamReader.read` and `StreamWriter.write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement TCP server and client using `asyncio streams`

**Edit** based on @user4815162342 great suggests:

I increased for `read` maximum number of bytes on chuck from 1 byte to 8192  bytes, it was my bad idea to use use the smallest possible number in the example and it could be misleading for other people.

In addition `BytesIO` is much better suited for concatenation than just `+=` bytes. I introduced `BytesIO` to this code example.

**Server Script Example:**

```py
import asyncio
import socket
from io import BytesIO


async def handler(reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    print(len(asyncio.all_tasks()))  # let's show number of tasks
    ip, port = writer.get_extra_info('peername')  # get info about incoming connection
    print(f"Incoming connection from {ip}: {port}")
    # better use BytesIO than += if you gonna concat many times
    all_data = BytesIO()
    while True:
        try:
            # read chunk up to 8 kbytes
            data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(8192), timeout=2.0)
            all_data.write(data)
            if reader.at_eof():
                print(f"Received data:\n{all_data.getvalue().decode('utf8')}")
                break
        except (asyncio.CancelledError, asyncio.TimeoutError):
            print("Too slow connection aborted")
            break

    writer.write(b"FROM_SERVER:\n")  # prepare data
    writer.write(all_data.getvalue())  # prepare more data
    # simulate slow server
    # await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await writer.drain()  # send all prepared data

    if writer.can_write_eof():
        writer.write_eof()

    writer.close()  # do not forget to close stream


async def main_server():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        client_connected_cb=handler,
        host="localhost",
        port=8888,
        family=socket.AF_INET,  # ipv4
    )

    ip, port = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f"Serving on: {ip}:{port}")
    print("*" * 200)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main_server())
```

**Client Script Example:**

```py
import asyncio
from io import BytesIO


async def main():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host="localhost", port=8888)
    # remove comment to test slow client
    # await asyncio.sleep(20)
    for i in range(10):
        writer.write(f"hello-{i}\n".encode("utf8"))  # prepare data
        await writer.drain()  # send data

    if writer.can_write_eof():
        writer.write_eof()  # tell server that we sent all data

    # better use BytesIO than += if you gonna concat many times
    data_from_server = BytesIO()  # now get server answer
    try:
        while True:
            # read chunk up to 8 kbytes
            data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(8192), timeout=1.0)
            data_from_server.write(data)
            # if server told use that no more data
            if reader.at_eof():
                break

        print(data_from_server.getvalue().decode('utf8'))
        writer.close()
    except ConnectionAbortedError:
        # if our client was too slow
        print("Server timed out connection")
        writer.close()
    except (asyncio.TimeoutError, asyncio.CancelledError):
        # if server was too slow
        print("Did not get answer from server due to timeout")
        writer.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to read the data 1 byte at a time. Use something like `reader.read(8192)` instead. Also, using `+=` to append data to `bytes` is somewhat of an antipattern; one should use `BytesIO` instead. Finally, you don't need to send EOF to a writer you are about to close.

Comment: @user4815162342 hello, can you say some words why you choose 8 kbytes, I decided to use 1 byte to separate very small amount of data (which I wanted to send in the test script). Absolutely agree with you regarding BytesIO. I have question regarding EOF, did you mean that there is no need to send EOF from server to client?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by separating small amounts of data, as you seem to be just appending them to `data_from_server`. Reading in larger blocks will just be more efficient, and if there is less than 8K of data available, asyncio will happily give it to you (8K is just the upper bound). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66285848/1600898) for a more detailed discussion of buffer sizes.

Comment: As for EOF, you are right, in this case it makes sense to send EOF before reading the data. I misread your code as calling `writer.write_eof()` immediately before calling `writer.close()`, which would not make sense.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes I wanted to read data exactly in several iterations of while loop, I mentioned it in comment `# wait not more than 1 second and read 1 byte only`, I agree that I should be more clear why I decided to do it. Thanks you for interesting link how to choose number of bytes to read.

Comment: But reading the data in 8k chunks will have the exact same effect, because as I said, if there is less data available, asyncio will just give it to you without waitting for full 8k (or whatever you specify). Reading 1 by 1 byte directly from asyncio is never a good idea, it will be horribly slow for any non-trivial amount of data. And even if it was somehow desirable for your previous use case, it should IMHO not be advertised in an answer to a question that didn't specify such a constraint.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes I agree. I edited the answer - increased max chunk size for `read` and introduced `BytesIO` to both client and server scripts. Thanks a lot for your suggests.

Comment: Nice. Another possible improvement is to break out of the loop `if data == b'': break` instead of checking for `at_eof()` - that is the idiomatic way to do it. Also, if you catch `CancelledError`, be sure to re-raise it, otherwise you swallow the cancellation.